# Add backtick character to mobile stack overflow

Tags: feature-request, markdown, mobile-web

The code formatting character, backtick, is (at least on my phone) extremely difficult to get on phone keyboards, if it's accessible at all.  Yet this character is needed constantly when leaving a quick comment or answer.  How about adding a button on the mobile page to insert a back tick?

Comment: For comments, or actual answers? (I’d suggest not answering on a phone specifically, but the code formatting button still exists, right?)

Comment: @minitech No. The mobile site is horrible. It's a text box. There's so much missing on the mobile site I can barely deal with it.

Comment: @minitech twice today (once me, once someone else) I saw a comment where code was not formatted with backticks - accompanied by an apology saying it was because the user was on a phone. And that's just today.  I see it commonly...